# How do I create a table from the data in a larger table using Excel functions?

Tags: excel, select, filter, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have the following table in Excel:

| **Code** | **Name** | **Location** | **Value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Name 01 | Regional | 1 |
| 1002 | Name 02 | Local | 2 |
| 1003 | Name 03 | Local | 3 |
| 1004 | Name 04 | Regional | 4 |
| 1005 | Name 05 | Local | 8 |
| 1006 | Name 06 | Regional | 6 |
| 1007 | Name 07 | Regional | 7 |
| 1008 | Name 08 | Local | 8 |
| 1009 | Name 09 | Regional | 9 |
| 1010 | Name 10 | Local | 10 |

From the table above, I want to create another table that meets the following criteria:

- Select only items whose Location is Local.
- From the items with Local Location select only the 3 highest values.

The result I expect is the following table:

| **Code** | **Name** | **Location** | **Value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1005 | Name 05 | Local | 8 |
| 1008 | Name 08 | Local | 8 |
| 1010 | Name 10 | Local | 10 |

I have already tried using the Excel functions `IF`, `CHOOSE`, `MAX` and `VLOOKUP` and some combinations between them, but without success.

Could someone help me create the table I want using some of the functions available in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ***Microsoft-365*** could use-

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A2:D11,C2:C11="Local"),4),-3)
```

If you want to include header row then use `VSTACK()`.

```
=VSTACK(A1:D1,TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A2:D11,C2:C11="Local"),4),-3))
```

[image]